# Вылетает c++ код

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int stepen(int x){
int y=1;
int forx;
for(forx=1;forx<x+1;forx++){
    y=y*10;
}
return y;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int summ=1;
    int presumm=1;
    int cuck;
    int for1;
    int for2;
    for(for1=stepen(n-1);for1<stepen(n);for1++){
            summ=1;
            presumm=1;
    for(for2=1;for2<n+1;for2++){
            presumm=for1%(stepen(for2));
            presumm=presumm/stepen(for2-1);
            summ=summ*presumm;
    };
if(for1%summ==0){cuck=for1;}
    }
    cout<<cuck;
    return 0;
}
```

Вылетает вот такой код.
А такой не вылетает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int stepen(int x){
int y=1;
int forx;
for(forx=1;forx<x+1;forx++){
    y=y*10;
}
return y;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int summ=1;
    int presumm=1;
    int cuck;
    int for1;
    int for2;
    for(for1=stepen(n-1);for1<stepen(n);for1++){
            summ=1;
            presumm=1;
    for(for2=1;for2<n+1;for2++){
            presumm=for1%(stepen(for2));
            presumm=presumm/stepen(for2-1);
           //summ=summ*presumm;
    };
if(for1%summ==0){cuck=for1;}
    }
    cout<<cuck;
    return 0;
}
```

В чем может быть проблема??

Comment: в том, что переменные нужно инициализировать

Comment: @DreamChild, где именно надо сделать? покажи

Comment: C переменными все в порядке. Дело в том, что вы делите на ноль

Answer (score 1):

`presumm=for1%(stepen(for2));`

При for1 = 10 и for2 = 1 остаток от деления будет 0.

`summ=summ*presumm;`

Будет нулём после этого.

И здесь:

`if(for1%summ==0)`

будет деление на ноль.